# Variable Speed Gearbox Mechanism

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics

[image]

Dear all, what is the gear mechanism  behind the variable speed drives gearbox? The one above has a lever which I believe helps to adjust the speed ratio between the input shaft and output shaft in a linear fashion. I am deciding to build my own gearbox using 3d-printing and I would need the output shaft to output from 300 to 400 rpm linearly by using a lever. Can anyone show a picture of the transmission gears?

Thank you